# WPF SelectedItem color disappears when the list loses the focus

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF `Window` which basically has a `ListBox` which displays a list of items.

I then have a `ListView` basically displaying the details of the `SelectedItem` in the `ListBox`.

The thing is, when the focus is not on the `ListBox` anymore, the highlighting color disappears and I cannot see which master item was selected anymore.

Do you know how I can solve this? (ie. making sure that the item stays highlighted)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way is to use a style on the ListBoxItem to override the default System colors:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Style.Resources>
      <!--SelectedItem with focus-->
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
         Color="LightBlue" Opacity=".4"/>
      <!--SelectedItem without focus-->
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
         Color="LightBlue" Opacity=".4"/>
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This is kind of a shortcut to the slightly more complex (but easier to control) method of defining the ItemTemplate for the list items.  There are plenty of examples of that online, so I won't put that here.

Comment: Both answers end up with the same solution, but I picked this one because the answer is included in the post.

Comment: for me the listbox always has the first item colored when the program starts is there a way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: I figured it out - I had the selected index bound to a variable in the viewmodel so in the VM constructor I just set that value to -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                       {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                        Path=IsSelected}" 
      Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Panel.Background" Value="Red" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved with data binding. 
If the ListView/ListBox SelectedItem is bound to a property in a ViewModel that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and the binding mode is "TwoWay", then when the ListView/ListBox gains focus again, the data binding will select automatically the previously selected item.