# how to keep blue selection in all the controls?

Tags: wpf, colors, wpf-controls, focus

I have two controls, and this two controls are wrapper in a general control. Each control has a datagrid. When I select an element in one of the datagrids, the selected item is marked in a blue color. But when I select an ilement in the second control, the selected intem in the first control is not blue, is a light grey that I can't see very well.

I know that this is because it is shown in blue the element in the control with the focus, but I would like to know if it's posible to leave marked with some color the elements selected in the controls that bave not the focus. For example I can use the blue color for the control with the focus and other color for the others controls, to indicate that this others controls have not the focus, but change the color for one more visible.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624320/wpf-selecteditem-color-disappears-when-the-list-loses-the-focus

Comment: You have to override default template of DataGridRow and remove trigger responsible for setting it to Gray color.